# If a linear map $H:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{m}$ is injective...

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

If a linear map $H:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{m}$ is injective, then there exists $c>0$ such that $\lvert Ax\rvert_{sup}\geq c\lvert x\rvert_{sup}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Here $\lvert x\rvert_{sup}=max\{\lvert x_i\rvert:i=1,...,n\}$.

I think that I'll want convert to show this is true for unit vectors, since then it'll work for vectors which are scaled to unit vectors... but I'm not sure where to begin in that pursuit. Any directions are appreciated.

Comment: If you're comfortable using some real analysis, it suffices to note that $H$ is continuous and that $\{x: |x|_{\sup} = 1\}$ is compact.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I'm okay with $H$ being continuous, but I'm not sure what it would mean for, in this case, the boundary of the unit cube to be compact. Or how this is sufficient if you don't mind explaining.

Comment: Continuous maps on a compact set attain their minimum.

Comment: @Tanner compact (since we're in $\Bbb R^n$) means closed and bounded.  Closed here means that a sequence on the boundary of the unit cube must  have its limit in the unit cube.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of $|x|_{sup}$, I will write $||x||_\infty$.

I will make the substitution $y = Ax$

Without loss of generality restrict your codomain to the the image so we can talk about $A^{-1}$

We have

$||A^{-1}y||_\infty = ||A^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i e_i ||_\infty$

$= ||\sum_{i=1}^n y_i A^{-1}e_i ||_\infty$

$\leq \sum_{i=1}^n |y_i|\cdot ||A^{-1}e_i ||_\infty$ (triangle inequality)

$\leq M \sum_{i=1}^n |y_i|$

where $M = max_i ||A^{-1}e_i ||_\infty$

Noting that $\sum_{i=1}^n |y_i| \leq n ||y||_\infty$

we see that

$||A^{-1}y||_\infty \leq M \sum_{i=1}^n |y_i|  \leq M n ||y||_\infty$

or

$\frac{1}{Mn}||x||_\infty \leq ||Ax||_\infty$

Note: $(e_1, ..., e_n)$ is really some arbitrary basis of Im $A$